# Angular 5: Iterate over [object].Array[object].[object].property with ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Typescript with the Angular Framework. 
I thought it would by a great starting point dealing with API data to learn some basics. 
This is the data i am getting from the APi
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

[Screenshot from the Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSEzI.png)

I have no idea how to iterate over the data to do someting like this.
How can I do this?

```
<ons-button (click)="getToplistByTotalVolume()">Aktualisieren</ons-button>
    <ons-list id="crypto-container" *ngFor="let toplistByTotalVolumeItem of toplistByTotalVolume; index as i">
      <ons-list-item>
        <div class="center">
            {{ toplistByTotalVolumeItem.FullName }}
        </div>
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
```

Here is the other code:

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CcapiService } from './shared/ccapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  toplistByTotalVolume: any;
  fiatCurrencies: string[];
  fiatCurrency: string = 'USD';


  constructor(private _data: CcapiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fiatCurrencies = ['EUR', 'USD'];
    this.getToplistByTotalVolume()
  }

  getToplistByTotalVolume() {
    this._data.serviceToplistByTotalVolume(this.fiatCurrency)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.toplistByTotalVolume = res;
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
}



// ccapi.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class CcapiService {

      result1:any;
      result2:any;

      constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

      serviceGetSingleSymbolPrice(fiatCurrency: string, exchanger?: string) {
        return this._http.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC&tsyms=${fiatCurrency}&e=${exchanger}`).map(result1 => this.result1 = result1);
      }

      serviceToplistByTotalVolume(fiatCurrency: string, exchanger?: string) {
        return this._http.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvol?limit=1&tsym=${fiatCurrency}`).map(result2 => this.result2 = result2);

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `toplistByTotalVolume` to equal the response in your subscription, which is an object that has the properties, `Data`, `Message`, `SponserData`, and `Type`. Then, each object in the `Data` array have the properties `CoinInfo` and `ConversionInfo`. So to display the name of each item, Iterate through the data of your `toplistByTotalVolumeObject` and access the name through the `CoinInfo`.

```
<ons-button (click)="getToplistByTotalVolume()">Aktualisieren</ons-button>
<ons-list id="crypto-container" *ngFor="let toplistByTotalVolumeItem of toplistByTotalVolume.Data;">
  <ons-list-item>
    <div class="center">
        {{ toplistByTotalVolumeItem.CoinInfo.FullName }}
    </div>
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

### Edit

To make this simpler, you could set `toplistByTotalVolumeItem` to specifically equal the data instead of the entire response. If you do this though, you won't have access to the other properties of the response, without saving it some other way, like for `Message`, `SponserData`, and `Type`.

```
getToplistByTotalVolume() {
  this._data.serviceToplistByTotalVolume(this.fiatCurrency)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.toplistByTotalVolume = res.Data; //<--Here
      console.log(res); //<--This will log the entire response
      console.log(this.toplistByTotalVolume); //<--This will only log the `Data` property of the response, which is your array
    });
}
```

Then you can just iterate through toplistByTotalVolume:

```
<ons-list id="crypto-container" *ngFor="let toplistByTotalVolumeItem of toplistByTotalVolume;">
```

But still, you would need to display the name with `{{toplistByTotalVolumeItem.CoinInfo.FullName}}` because each data item is an object with `CoinInfo` and `ConversionInfo`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly.
Just one more question. Is this the best way or is there any "better" solution?
Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelUsw There isn't really much to do to make this "better" since its a pretty simple use case as it is. But I edited the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two object which has fieldnamed FullName, you should access it as,

```
  <ons-list-item>
    <div class="center">
        {{ toplistByTotalVolumeItem.CoinInfo.FullName }}
    </div>
  </ons-list-item>
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan.
Thanks for your quick reply. But this is not working.
I am getting the following error:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: @MichaelUsw Hi michael

Comment: @MichaelUsw sorry missed your comment, you should assign as  this.toplistByTotalVolume = res.data;

Comment: mark if the answer helped :) first come first serve :P